# Prepend perl program with filter

Tags: perl, pipe

I want to write:

```
... | my_filter | myperlprogram
```

But I do not know how to run `my_filter` until I have started `myperlprogram`.

Can I somehow in `myperlprogram` loop STDIN through `my_filter` before reading it?

I am thinking something like:

```
pipe($a,$b);
if(not fork()) {
   close STDOUT; 
   open STDOUT, $b;
   exec "my_filter --with the correct --options";
} else {
   close STDIN
   open STDIN, $a
}
# continue reading STDIN now looped through `my_filter`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not at all clear from the description why a simple

```
open STDIN, '-|', 'your_filter', '--option1', ...
```

will not do.

Comment: So much more elegant. I will need to try it for real, but the 5 minute test looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see the problem is: To filter the `STDIN` for the script, by using an external program which is run from inside the script once the script is running (so, not with a pipeline).   With [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use IPC::Run qw(start pump finish);

my $filtered_in;
FILTER_IN: {        
    my @cmd = qw(a_filter.pl);  # add filter's options/arguments
    my $h = start \@cmd, \my $in, \$filtered_in;
    while (<>) { 
        $in = $_; 
        pump $h while length $in;

        # Wait for filter's output -- IF WANT to process lines as received
        pump $h until $filtered_in =~ /\n\z/;
        chomp $filtered_in;                    # process/use filter's output
        $filtered_in .= '|';                   # as it's coming (if needed)
    }    
    finish $h or die "Cleanup returned: $?";
};    
say $filtered_in // 'no input';
```

This allows one to process filter's lines of output as they are emitted. If that is not needed but we only want to accumulate filter's output for later then you don't need the code under `# Wait for...`

---

Simplest test with `a_filter.pl` such as

```
use warnings;
use strict;
STDOUT->autoflush(1);

my $cnt = 0;    
while (<>) { print "line ", ++$cnt, ": ", $_ }
```

and then run

```
echo "a\nfew\nlines" | script.pl
```

with output

```
line 1: a|line 2: few|line 3: lines|
```

from our toy processing in `script.pl` above.

This will filter input via a file as well,

```
script.pl < input.txt
```